# script using linux command to search word

Tags: awk, sed, grep, cat, cut

I have the file, In the file data few lines have  only one word, if such a case is present i want to print following line as the present line

can I get some tips for this

```
grep -E "module" filename   # to fetch the line which contains the "module"
```

after module, if there is no string consider 2nd line as extension of the module line

example

```
module module_name1(i1,i2,i3)
statement1;
statement2;
statement3;
   .
   .
statement;

module 
module_name2(i1,i2,i3)   #observe here
statement1;
statement2;
statement3;
   .
   .
statement;

module module_name3(i1,i2,i3)
statement1;
statement2;
statement3;
   .
   .
statement;

module module_name4(i1,i2,i3)
statement1;
statement2;
statement;
   .
   .
statement;
```

output expected

```
module_name1(i1,i2,i3)
module_name2(i1,i2,i3)
module_name3(i1,i2,i3)
module_name4(i1,i2,i3)
```

what output i get

```
module_name1(i1,i2,i3)
                         #missing
module_name3(i1,i2,i3)
module_name4(i1,i2,i3)
```

missing place i want consider next as present line

Comment: I'm not sure I understand you correctly. Would you have an example input and an example output?

Comment: @MarcusMüller check once i update the quetion

Comment: sed '/module/{n;s/.""/\n/}'   command what i tried

Comment: Thanks! This looks a bit like a programming language, is there not a parser for it that you could directly ask to give you a list of modules?

Comment: may I know how to remove a multiple strings between two string consider multiple lines also

Comment: Sure! That's a good problem :)

Answer (score 1):

Something like that:

```bash
grep -A 1 "^module" < filename | sed -n -e 's/^\(module \)*\(.*(.*)\).*$/\2/p'
```

Explanations:

1. `grep ...`

- Filter on lines begin by "module"
- Return the found lines and one line after each found line (`-A 1`)
  Output:

```
module module_name1(i1,i2,i3)
statement1;
--
module
module_name2(i1,i2,i3)   #observe here
statement1;
--
...
```

1. `sed ...`

- `-n`: Do not print (quiet mode)
- `-e`: Script follow...
- `s/^\(module \)*\(.*(.*)\).*$/\2/p` : The script

  - `s/.x./.y./.a.` : substitute/replace `.x.` token by `.y.` token and follow `.a.` arguments

    - `.x.` is `^\(module \)*\(.*(.*)\).*$` :

      - search for `module` token at beginning (prefix `^`) of line or not (`*`). It's is the first marked pattern `\(...\)`
      - the second pattern `\(...\)` contains any characters `.*` (for you the module name) followed by parenthesis token `(...)` (without backslashes), for you the module parameters. Any characters between parenthesis `.*`
      - followed by any characters `.*` until the end of line `$`
    - `.y.` is `\2`

      - The second patern between parenthesis
    - `.a.` is `p`

      - `p` is for forced print (instead of `-n` option) so `.y.` is printed

Output:

```
module_name1(i1,i2,i3)
module_name2(i1,i2,i3)
module_name3(i1,i2,i3)
module_name4(i1,i2,i3)
```

Comment: thanks for the answer sed -n -e 's/^\(module \)*\(.*(.*)\).*$/\2/p'  thals for this

Comment: can give explanation for this, so i can understand the command(sed command things, grep i got it)

Comment: if the module name starts with the next line its not fetching@ArnaudValmary

Comment: Do you have an example of file content ?

Comment: I have added explanations

Answer (score 1):

```
$ perl -ne 'if (s/^module\s*//) { $_ = <> if ($_ eq ""); s/\).*/)/; print }' file
module_name1(i1,i2,i3)
module_name2(i1,i2,i3)
module_name3(i1,i2,i3)
module_name4(i1,i2,i3)
```

This perl one-liner reads each input line (`-n` option) and tries to remove the word "module" and any trailing spaces from the start of the line.

If that succeeds, it then checks to see if the current line is now empty.  If it is, it reads in the next line (`$_ = <>`).  Either way, it removes everything after the first `)` character (`s/\).*/)/`) and prints the modified line.

If the `s/^Module\s*//` operation fails, then nothing is printed and the script continues on to the next line of input.

Answer (score 0):

Shorter:

```
$ grep -o 'module_name[0-9].*' file
module_name1(i1,i2,i3)
module_name2(i1,i2,i3)
module_name3(i1,i2,i3)
module_name4(i1,i2,i3)
```